# How to define pattern in mapping rules for url path parameter

Tags: 3scale

When there is parameter in url, how to set pattern for mapping rule in svc configuration? for example, url like this: http://myaddress/hr/{deptId}/header, the deptId is department id which is a dynamic string.
I tested with /hr/*/header, it doesn't work, 404 has been returned.

Answer (score 1):

Using {deptId} in url will solve it.